mostrar una imagen en dompdf
ya he visto varios tutoriales y ninguno me ha podido ayudar a resolver mi problema, estoy tratando de mostrar las imagenes de unos productos si coloco la variable $producto['imagen'] me muestra el nombre de la imagen perfectamente.. pero cuando  coloco la ruta especifica de la imagen
 `$html .= '<td><img src= "./assets/img/"' . $producto['imagen'] . '"></td>';`

me sale un cuadro con una x y me dice Image not found or type unknown, no es la ruta (ya que la he comprobado) no es el formato por que esta en jpg... ya no se que hacer para que me muestre las imagenes.. dejo la estructura del codigo por aqui...
<?php

 use Dompdf\Dompdf;

  require_once '../vendor/autoload.php'; // Incluye la biblioteca DomPDF

  require_once "../config/conexion.php";

  $id = $_GET['pedidoId'];
  $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE id = $id");
   $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  $productos = json_decode($result['productos'], true);
   $total_general = 0; // Inicializar el total general
   $html = '

para no ponerlo largo pondre solo la variable de la imagen
foreach ($productos as $producto) {

$subtotal = $producto['cantidad'] * $producto['precio'];
$total_general += $subtotal; // Sumar al total general
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td><img src= "./assets/img/"' . $producto['imagen'] . '"></td>';

// Crea una instancia de Dompdf
 $dompdf = new Dompdf();

 // Carga el HTML en Dompdf
 $dompdf->loadHtml($html, 'UTF-8');

 // Renderiza el PDF
 $dompdf->render();


 // Guarda el PDF en el servidor
  $dompdf->stream($id.'-orden.pdf',array('Attachment' => 0));


  ?>

cuando imprimo el pdf me sale todo bien pero la imagen asi...



Cual es el html de resultado ? Las imagenes existen en el directorio? la extension está agregada ? Cual es el error de la consola sobre la imagen ?

no es la ruta (ya que la he comprobado) ¿De qué modo la has comprobado? Si revisas la consola y tienes un 404 con respecto a la imagen, entonces SÍ es un problema de la ruta. Por favor, completa la pregunta mostrando las depuraciones que has hecho con respecto a la ruta. Si son correctas entonces buscaremos la causa en otra parte. Por el momento hay que agotar la pista principal.

Asumiendo que la ruta es correcta, si el problema persiste, intenta poner esta configuración $dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true); justo debajo de la línea donde creas la instancia de la clase. Ver esta pregunta para más detalles.

Probaste a poner la ruta de assets no empezando por ./ si no simplemente /, sin el punto?
